# Authentication & Authorization with H2 database in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, h2

I want to make an Authentication & Authorization with H2 Database in Spring boot and I need a resource to read and learn and see an example code.
please help me!
tnx

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend site *springframework.guru* .

Here is a post which can help you with your problem:

*https://springframework.guru/using-the-h2-database-console-in-spring-boot-with-spring-security/*

Good luck :)